# how to style opacity in addEventListner?

Tags: coding-style, mouseevent, addeventlistener, opacity, mouseenter

```
const mainDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('home-bg-image');
const homeMainDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('home-bg');
const homeDiv = document.getElementById('home-1');




homeDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
    mainDiv.style.opacity = '0';
    homeMainDiv.style.opacity = '1';
    console.log('Working !!!')
});
```

**I got this Error**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.

Answer (score 0):

`documents.getElementsByClassName` returns an array.

You should access the element you want to style by using the brackets notation

```
mainDiv[0].style.opacity = '0';
homeMainDiv[0].style.opacity = '1';
```